# Can anyone tell me the use of address?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

As when I was doing an exercise about English reading, the word address is in my way. I can't think about its other meanings rather than as a noun (mean where you live) and a verb (usually used in giving a speech). Here is a picture with the word address in the third statement. Can anyone tell me the meaning?[image]

Comment: As used in C it's your "a verb (usually used in giving a speech)". Honestly that seems straightforward and easy, so I'm not sure why you didn't see that.

Comment: I know the word address has a meaning of giving a speech, or we can make a sentence that "He will address a speech", in which the word "address" can be replaced by "give ". But can it be replaced by "give " in statement c? If can't, what is the exact meaning here?

Comment: "He will address a speech" for "give a speech" is _not_ normal usage. "Address" means "speak to". However, oddly enough you _can_ say something like "He addressed his remarks to the young people in the audience".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The meaning of “to address” in your example, “being able to address large groups of people,” is “to speak to,” or “to give a talk or a speech to.”

You could have had your answer much sooner simply by looking up, “to address,” in any number of online dictionaries.  It is not necessary to come to a grammar website such as this one to ask the definition of a word.

Google Online Dictionary

ad•dress
əˈdres,ˈaˌdres/

verb
2.
speak to (a person or an assembly), typically in a formal way.
"she addressed an audience of the most important Shawnee chiefs"
synonyms:   talk to, give a talk to, speak to, make a speech to, give a lecture to, lecture, preach to, give a sermon to…

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Maybe at first I didn't make myself clearly understood as I think that address can only be followed by a noun that refers to something and moreover I deem that it can't be followed by a noun refering to someone. So that is why "address large groups of people" would confuse me. But now I understand that address can be followed both "a speech " and someone. Thank you for your explaination.

Comment: @JoyJo - One would **not** normally write "address a speech" (unless followed by the identification of the audience).  One **does** "address an audience".